# Unsupported get request when trying to read ad_id with Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, http

I'm building a Facebook application that uses a webhook to read Facebook leads. The application is now working fine: every new lead in my campaigns are sent via the webhook to my script, with the needed information about the lead: ad_id, form_id, leadgen_id and so.

Now, I am trying to get some additional information with the Facebook Graph API based on the ad_id, form_id and leadgen_id and I'm having issues with this. I tried the Facebook Graph API in both PHP curl, and a direct HTTP GET call, and I'm having the same issue in both ways.

When I try to fetch the lead object using leadgen_id, it works fine, and I can get the name, email and phone that I need.

When I try to fetch the form object using form_id, it also works fine, and I manage to get the form name.

But when I try to fetch the ad object using the ad_id (since I need the name of the ad) it gives me the following error: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '23848043174300142' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions".

Currently I have the following permissions (advanced access): pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_metadata, pages_show_list, leads_retrieval, public_profile, ads_management.

Is it an issue with the permissions or with my call?
I tried both PHP curl, and a direct HTTP GET call, and I'm having the same issue in both.

My HTTP GET call to retrieve the ad's name (based on ads_id) is the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/ADS_ID?access_token=MY_LONG_TIME_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

(when I'm replacing ads_id with leadgen_id or with form_id, it gives me the relevant object without any problem).

Thanks,
David

Comment: hi @David Cohen were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I will be glad to have an answer to my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if this comes up late, I just had a very similar issue and the solution was to go to the Business Manager then Business Settings > Integrations > Leads access and assign the user that we are using the token for to the corresponding brand.

Facebook explains it here under Note: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/

Hope this helps some people.